# Add permissions to a mute command but encountering an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.7

I'm trying to setup permissions for a mute command but they're not working & I don't know how to fix them

It's a pretty simple mute command, just the permissions I'm stuck on

````
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
 arg=reason
 author=ctx.author
 guild=ctx.message.guild
 perms=discord.Permissions(connect=False, speak=False, read_text_channels_and_see_voice_channels=False, add_reactions=False, send_messages=False)
 role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="muted")

 await guild.create_role(name="muted", colour=discord.Colour(0x808080), permissions=perms)
 await member.send(f'You got muted for: ```\n{arg}\n``` Muted by: {author}')
 await member.add_roles(role)
 await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} got muted for: ```\n{arg}\n``` Muted by: {author}!')
````

the error is: 
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connect'`
I'm sure I'll get similar errors for the other permissions, I don't know how to fix it though, anyone able to help?

Comment: `Permissions` doesn't like the `connect` argument; what makes you think it should?

Comment: @DrJakaboii Side Note: I couldn't find a `read_text_channels_and_see_voice_channels` attribute for the `Permissions` class, perhaps you're looking for `connect` (which you already have) along with `read_messages`?

Comment: This isn't going to work.  The default_role likely grants users the right to read messages, connect, etc., and a user gets all of the permissions that any of their roles give them. Instead, you need to modify the channels of your guild to have `PermissionOverwrites` for the muted role that explicitly remove permissions for that channel.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm going to try, if all goes well when someone has the muted role they won't be able to see anything except a ```muted``` channel (which I'm going to make the bot create)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [initialiser for `Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.1/api.html#discord.Permissions) expects a number, the permission value. Instead of passing the keyword arguments into the initialiser, pass them into the [`update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.1/api.html#discord.Permissions.update) method, which accepts keyword arguments.

```
perms=discord.Permissions()
perms.update(connect=False, speak=False, read_text_channels_and_see_voice_channels=False, add_reactions=False, send_messages=False)
```